# Restrict Upload of Any Image Other Than a Specific One in Flask or Bottle

Tags: python, flask

It seems that every question related to this one is asking about restricting uploads by file size, etc.

I am creating an online demo of an application using Bottle (similar to Flask). Part of the program requires a user to download a very specific image and then upload it to see the result of a crop operation done on that image. The image is very particular, so I am trying to save the user time in using the demo, but also prevent shifty image files from being uploaded to the server.

My question is, is it possible to restrict the upload to only that particular image. Is there a way to know that an image uploaded is not that exact image?

For stub testing, I just did the following:

```
myimg = request.files.get("myimg")
fname = myimg.filename
if fname == "bob.jpeg" or fname == "sally.jpeg":
   do what the app needs to do
else:
   return "Only the demo images are allowed"
```

Obviously, restricting it by filename is silly because anyone can just rename a new file.

I was thinking perhaps that an image could be turned into some kind of special array, and then I can compare the two arrays, or is there a more elegant solution?

Any help/ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If only one particular image is allowed, then what is the point of having the user upload it?  Why does the server not have the image file already?

Comment: The application crops the image based on features in the image. The demo is just for showing how it works, but (1) the user would need to search hard for a similar image and (2) I didn't want abuse on the site, with someone sending a shifty photo to the server when they test it out

Comment: Note that if you truly want to do this /before/ it's uploaded, you will need to do this in javascript or some other in-client mechanism, not in the bottle web server. That cannot do anything with the image prior to it being uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To confirm whether the uploaded file is indeed the one you expect, simply examine its bytes and compare them to the known, good, file. You can either checksum the incoming bytes yourself (using, say, [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html)), or use [`filecmp.cmp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html#filecmp.cmp) (which I think is simpler, assuming you have a copy of the acceptable image on disk where the server can read it).

For example:

```
uploaded_img = request.files.get("myimg")
if not filecmp.cmp(uploaded_img.filename, "/path/to/known/good/image", shallow=False):
    raise ValueError("An unexpected file was uploaded")
```

Comment: What a clean solution! Thank you!